# SSH - root login disabled, password disabled. Still need a complex root password for local sessions?

Tags: security, openssh

If this computer's openssh server requires keys for SSH logins, do I still need to have a complex password? Given that this is a private single-user computer in a secure building.

Comment: What other network-accessible services are running?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The only such service I am aware of is postfix configured to forward cron mail to my gmail account.